# Euclid's lemma proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof the uniqueness of **q** and **r** in $$a=bq+r$$ where **a** and **b** are positive integers and $$0\leq r <b$$
A claim can be made like this ...

Let $$a=bq_{1}r_{1}$$ where $$0\leq r_{1}<b$$ and $$a = bq+r$$ where $$0\leq r<b$$
Therefore, $$bq_{1}r_{1} = bq+r$$ 
$$bq_{1}-bq=r-r_{1}$$
$$b(q_{1}-q)=r-r_{1}$$
Therefore $$b|r-r_{1}$$
Now, how can we prove $$r-r_{1}=0 $$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $0\le r<b$ and $0\ge -r_1>-b$, it must be true that $r-r_1<b$ and $r-r_1>-b$. This means that $|r-r_1|<b$. But $b|(r-r_1)$; the only way to have $c|d$ when $|d|<c$ is when $d=0$, so we must have $r=r_1$.

Comment: Thanks. My textbook gives another proof of this lemma using **Bezout's identity**. But bezout's identity itself is based on this **lemma** and its derived **Division Algorithm**. So how is this proof justified?